# Question on AJAX Library (like DWR)

Tags: java, ajax, javascript, dwr

I have a web app which uses AJAX library (DWR) to get data dynamically
i.e. as user clicks on some table items, it dynamically gets details for that item by making a DWR call...It actually gets the complete HTML code as string for the table (Actually in the background, a Java method does the processing and returns the HTML string)...So the usage is like this;

```
someDWRObj.someJavaMethod(someData,callBackFunction);
```

I am sure MOST of you would say that this is NOT at all a GOOD practice..

So my question is, is DWR an outdated technology, what are the replacements for DWR technology (more specifically to implement what i am trying to do above) ? Can DOJO do what DWR does ?

All the questions assume that I'll be using Java in the middle tier..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing if from scratch again then you could consider some existing frameworks like GWT or Vaadin. If not, then I guess you could just use a REST web services on the server side exposing your existing functionality using REST with JSON objects and on the client side (html page) you can parse JSON data with JQuery to suit your needs.